# Trying to replicate callBack hell

Tags: javascript, callback

I have been trying to learn about callBack hell, and was trying to replicate and then change it into promises. Here is my code, **its saying on execution cb is not a function**

What i am missing here.

```js
var t = addTwo(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a * b);
  divideTwo(function() {
    console.log("arshita");
  })
})

function addTwo(cb) {
  cb(3, 4);
}

function divideTwo(cb1) {

}
addTwo();
```

Comment: because `addTwo();` calls it without a function.

Comment: Sorry sir, i didnt, i am actully pretty confused to replicate callBack hell, can u just give me a simple code and how to use it. it would be much easier for me to understand

Comment: Yes you did call it without a function. Look at the last line in your code. You have addTwo() and there is no argument in it. You do it correct at the top of the code where you pass in the function to it..

Comment: Yes, i saw that. :-(\

Comment: callback hell is when a callback has a callback which in turn also has a callback which in turn... you get the drift. So if you're doing only one layer of function with a single callback - this is not a _real_ hell ;)

Comment: thats what the issue is, there are tons of example, that is making me confused, i just want a simple callBack hell program full implemented. Like just copy paste and bam its working, and then i will experiment over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code

```
var t = addTwo(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a * b);
  divideTwo(function() {
    console.log("arshita");
  })
})

function addTwo(cb) {
  cb(3, 4);
}

function divideTwo(cb1) {

}
addTwo((a, b) => a + b); // <----- Here you passed nothing, though `addTwo` 
// expected a callback. I wrote an example callback that sums `a` and `b`
```

**Update**

If you want to see what callback hell looks like, then have a look at this (a simple, only 3-level callback hell):

```
function init(msg, cb) {
  alert(msg)
  cb()
}

function running(msg, cb) {
  alert(msg)
  cb()
}

function finish(msg) {
  alert(msg)
}

// The below code may not be considered as "callback hell" yet, but add few more iterations and it definitely will become a hell
init('program started!', function() {
  running('program is running', function() {
    finish('program shut downs')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i want.